# How to fix arguments for scale_x_date in R code (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please I need your help to find the error in this code. I am receiving the following error message: `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`. I think the problem is with `scale_x_date`arguments, but I am unable to fix it.  Thank you.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)

entrada<- read_excel("R_codes_examples/entrada_turistas.xlsx", sheet = "mensal", col_types = 
c("date", "numeric"))
ggplot(entrada, aes(x = entrada$`mes_ano`, y = entrada$`movimento_de_passageiros`)) +
geom_line( colour = "#0c4c8a") + 
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months",labels = date_format("%b-%Y"),limits = c(as.Date("2006- 
08-01"), NA)) +
scale_y_continuous(labels=function(n){format(n, scientific = FALSE)}) +
labs(y= "Movimento de Passageiros mensais 2006 a 2017 ", x = "Mês/Ano") +
xlab("") +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

Please find the head of my code below:

```
    > dput(head(entrada))
  structure(list(mes_ano = structure(c(1136073600, 1138752000, 
  1141171200, 1143849600, 1146441600, 1149120000), tzone = "UTC", 
  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), movimento_de_passageiros = 
  c(119764, 100442, 114198, 
  124676, 113431, 115482)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = 
  c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Check the class of `entrada$\`mes_ano\``. As the error message is telling you: `scale_x_date` works with objects of class Date only. BTW: Get rid of `entrada$`. Simply use `aes(x = \`mes_ano\`, ...)`.

Comment: try entrada<-as.data.frame(entrada)

Comment: We can only speculate without showing us (part) of your data. Most likely your dates are stored as characters and not with a date class. Try to provide us with a dput(head(entrada)) so we can actually help you.

Comment: @KeltonSantos I would replace the geom_line( colour = "#0c4c8a") with geom_col()

Comment: @Rfanatic I've tried but I got he same error. Thank you.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg I just posted the head() below

Comment: we still cannot see if it is a string or a date

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg can you check it now?

Comment: I have given the answer now to get your graph working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that went wrong and yes your data was correct :)

1. Change `labels = date_format("%b-%Y")` to `date_labels = "%b-%Y"`
2. Your limits cannot contain one NA value as where does it need to stop? this cannot be an infinite date.
3. Limits must be in `POSIXct` format
4. Just some code style things, `entrada$'mes_ano'` is not needed as you already passed the data and you can call x and y just by its name.

So here the fixed code assuming you work with POSIXct data (including time):

```
ggplot(entrada, aes(x = mes_ano, y = movimento_de_passageiros)) +
geom_line(colour = "#0c4c8a") + 
scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b-%Y", limits = c(as.POSIXct("2006-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2006-12-01"))) +
scale_y_continuous(labels=function(n){format(n, scientific = FALSE)}) +
labs(y= "Movimento de Passageiros mensais 2006 a 2017 ", x = "Mês/Ano") +
xlab("")`
```

Here an example if you work with as.Date dates, then make sure all has the same format

```
ggplot(entrada, aes(x = as.Date(mes_ano), y = movimento_de_passageiros)) +
  geom_line(colour = "#0c4c8a") + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%b-%Y", limits = c(as.Date("2006-01-01"), as.Date("2006-12-01"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(n){format(n, scientific = FALSE)}) +
  labs(y= "Movimento de Passageiros mensais 2006 a 2017 ", x = "Mês/Ano") +
  xlab("")
```

Comment: Thank you @Merijn van Tilborg, it works just fine. I should have used `scale_x_datetime` rather than `scale_x_date`

Comment: good point, I used some code I had laying around that matched up with your problem and there I used `scale_x_datetime` I will update my answer using either one of them. for both them your date(time) format needs to be consistent.